# using HtmlHelper in javascript with MVC and DataAnnotations jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, data-annotations

I created an extension method that works when it is not included in a java script tag.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string TickWrap(this HtmlHelper source, MvcHtmlString mvcHtmlString)
    {
        return "'" + mvcHtmlString.ToHtmlString().Replace("'", "''") + "'";
    }
}
```

usage in my view is as follows

```
@Html.TickWrap(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.SampleDateTime))
```

All it's doing is grabbing the Display Name attribute of the Data Annotation listed below and displaying it as 'Date and Time' with the ticks around it.

```
[Display(Name = "Date and Time")]
public DateTime SampleDateTime {get; set;}
```

I can't seem to get this to work in a script tag however.  I am getting a JavaScript critical error syntax error.  Below is the script that is included in my view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var displayName = @Html.TickWrap(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.SampleDateTime))
        alert(displayName);
    });
</script>
```

**I'm guesing it has to do with the usage of the HtmlHelper in the script section?  If so how can I use in the script section?**

That is a simplified version of what I have going on but what I'm really trying to do is to populate the colNames for a jqGrid without having to hard code them in the javascript.  I'd like to use the Data Annotations so I only have to change in one spot.  The colNames for the jqGrid gets defined as

```
colNames: ['ParameterId','Location', 'Parameter Name', 'Date and Time', 'Parameter Value']
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `''` (quotes) around `@Html.TickWrap(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.SampleDateTime))` ?

Comment: That's what my extension method @Html.TickWrap is for...it wraps the Display Name attribute dictated by the Data Annotation with 'My custom display name'

Comment: I think my problem has to do something with how @Html is being used in script tag and not the normal rending of the html but I'm not sure.  I'm pretty new to MVC

Comment: I find that most times when I use MVC @commands inside javascript they have to be encased in quotes. Try it and I wouldn't be surprised if that gets it working. If it does I'll put up a formal answer.

Comment: yes the manual single ticks worked

var displayName = '@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.SampleDateTime)'

but this begs the question of how to get it to work with HtmlHelper Extension that wraps with ticks ''...I guess I'm not sure that it matters...but I'll try in the morning to set the colNames like I stated with this method.

Comment: Why are the ticks manually necessary?  Why don't they work with extension method.  My idea was to replace all ' with '' in the display name data annotation incase the display name had "Dan's comments" with "Dan''s comments"

Comment: The quotes escape out and let you use your Razor code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put '' (quotes) around @Html.TickWrap(Html.DisplayNameFor(m => Model.SampleDateTime))

Comment: I accepted as answer because it put me in the right direction.  For whatever reason the HtmlHelper code needs to be enclosed in quotes when in the script tags.  I don't even need the TickWrap extension method.

Comment: In the end I populated the colNames for the jqGrid with the metadata in the Data Annotations by using this

colNames: [
            '@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => headerMetadata.ParameterId)',
            '@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => headerMetadata.Location.DisplayName)',
            '@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => headerMetadata.Parameter.DisplayName)',
            '@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => headerMetadata.SampleDateTime)',
            '@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => headerMetadata.ParameterValue1)'
        ],

Comment: @Dan P I'm not sure if you actually accepted it, it was upvoted but not accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Data Annotations you should create Class that Extend from Attribute Class. And Than Get the value using PropertyInfo reflection.

If you want to populate the colNames for a jqGrid using data anotation, i already upgrade my jq.grid Plugin to support data annotation, check this [jq.grid](http://aiskahendra.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/asp-net-mvc-jqgrid-nuget-v-1-1-0/) for more information